# When I am trying to execute django core management code in the function it doesn't work

Tags: python, django, web, file-upload, view

I need to upload cvs data to database and I wrote the code which did it. but I need to do it triggered: every time user upload file - the python script update the database. 
In my code: I have call_command('uploadDb') when I place it not in function upload - it works, but when I place it inside the upload function - it didnt 
What is the problem?
Thank you

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
from django.core.management import call_command



# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Upload the file</h1>")

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.htm', {'what':'File Upload'})

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']))
        return HttpResponse("Successful")

    return HttpResponse("Failed")

def handle_uploaded_file(file, filename):
    if not os.path.exists('upload/'):
        os.mkdir('upload/')

    with open('upload/' + filename, 'wb+') as destination:

        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)


call_command('uploadDb')
```

uploadDb function in /management/commands

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from data.models import MyCsvModel
from data.models import MyCsvModel2
from data.models import MyCsvModel3
from data.models import MyCsvModel4

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Command to do import to database'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            my_csv_list = MyCsvModel.import_data(data = open("C:\\Users\\kz938vk\\Desktop\\client.csv"))
            my_csv_list2 = MyCsvModel2.import_data(data = open("C:\\Users\\kz938vk\\Desktop\\product.csv"))
            my_csv_list3 = MyCsvModel3.import_data(data = open("C:\\Users\\kz938vk\\Desktop\\payment.csv"))
            my_csv_list4 = MyCsvModel4.import_data(data = open("C:\\Users\\kz938vk\\Desktop\\messages.csv"))
            print("I am here")
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            CommandError(repr(e))
```

Comment: The code formatting is unclear. You should copy the code directly from the source file, paste it as a plain text inside your post, select it and press curly brackets in the edit panel to make it formatted as a code.

Comment: thank you for the comment, it is updated

Comment: What does the `uploadDb` command look like. It might be better to extract the code into a separate function, then call that function in the `upload` function and in the management command.

Comment: I thought so as well, but it didnt worked as well. It works only when it is written there alone

Comment: "it didn't work as well" isn't enough information. What did you try, and what was the result?

Comment: In the code above, `call_command` is executed only when import or directly execute the file with Django handlers definitions (the top snippet). If you want it to run on each upload, you have to add the call in `handle_uploaded_file`, after the `with` block - especially if you want to have the access to the uploaded file from the command.